# Do not load image for a particular site in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I don't want to load the images when i visit some website .Are there any plug-in of firefox can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adblock plus will allow you to do this.

Right click on an image on the site.

Click Adblock Plus: Block image...

A dialog will appear, "Look for Pattern"

Select the one matching http://www.domain.com/*

Comment: But don't forget to add ".jpg" on the end otherwise you'll block the entire site. You'll have to add a filter for "gif" and "png" images as well.

Answer (score 15):

In Firefox, goto Tools > Options > Load Images Automatically -> Exceptions

Add site and say Block and Close

[image]

Comment: +1 for suggesting a solution WITHOUT the help of add-ons.

Comment: These options are no longer shown by default in Firefox 38 and later. To get the preference back, first turn off the [new Options panel](http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-firefox-38/) in about:config by setting browser.preferences.inContent to false, then install the [SettingSanity add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/settingsanity/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a greasemonkey script to do this.

This question might be close to this one in SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387260/removing-images-with-greasemonkey

Answer (score 0):

[Nuke Anything Enhanced](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/951/) can also do this on a one time basis if you do not want to blacklist something forever or have to worry about managing a list of blocked content.